# Run JAX-WS on JavaME

Tags: java-me, jax-ws

I have simple web service application created on JAX-WS. I need to move this application on embedded device that runs Java micro edition. Is it possible run JAX-WS on Java micro edition?

```
public class Srv 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/RFIDMngr", new Mngr());
    }

}
```

What is the best way to move web service application to JavaME?

Comment: Do you mean to run a server on embedded device?

Comment: yes, I would like to run server on embedded device